# Why do identical data barcodes look different visually?

Tags: java, barcode

I'm encountering a discrepancy between two barcodes with identical content but different raw bytes. One barcode is generated using an online tool called Labelary, designed for creating ZPL Labels, and the other is generated in my Java code using the ZXing library. Despite having the same content, the visual appearance of the barcodes differs.

##### My Barcode

[image: My barcode]

**Raw text:** 12345678 
**Raw bytes:** 69 0c 22 38 4e 2f 6a

`BarcodeGenerator.java`

```
public byte[] getBarCode128(String data, int width, int height) {
    Code128Writer writer = new Code128Writer();
    BitMatrix matrix = writer.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, width, height);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(matrix, "png", outputStream);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Main.java`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "12345678";
        
    int width = (int) (data.length() * 11 * moduleWidth);
    int height = 270;
        
    BarcodeGenerator barcode = new BarcodeGenerator();
    byte[] barcodeImageBytes = barcode.getBarCode128(data, (int) width, (int) height);
}
```

##### Barcode from Labelary

Click [here](https://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=4&height=2&units=inches&index=0&rotation=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5EBY5%2C2%2C270%0A%5EFO0%2C0%5EBC%2C%2CN%5EFD12345678%5EFS%0A%0A%5EXZ) to view source code.

[image: Barcode from Labelary]

**Raw text:** 12345678 
**Raw bytes:** 68 11 12 13 14 15 16 17   18 3c 6a

What could be the potential reasons for this discrepancy, and how can I ensure correct barcode generation using the ZXing library in Java?

Comment: Comparing the result of `aA1` from both tools, I believe this is because ZXing automatically infers the appropriate subtype, but your ZPL code doesn't. See page 95 for discussion https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/BC_Command.pdf, if you want your ZPL code to produce identical results to ZXing then you'll have to set the appropriate subset or allow automatic subset. If you want your Java code to use a specific subset, it seems Zxing doesn't support manual subset selection so you'll have to find another library

Comment: Ah, this ZPL code `FD>;12345678` will result in identical barcode as your Zxing code

Comment: Do you have a Documentation reference for the ^FD>; I've never seen it before and would like to figure out how it works in detail.

Comment: In the PDF I shared in the earlier comment, it's the Start Code C for all numeric code

Comment: @Martheen, thanks - I managed to find it. Any insights on which mode corresponds to each subset (A/B/C)? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are correct, just different encodings.
The `69` one is Code C with two digits per code point. The longer `68` one is Code B.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128

If you want to force your code to also do the longer code B, you could set the [FORCE_CODE_SET](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/EncodeHintType.html#FORCE_CODE_SET) encode hint to "B".

Wild guess about the encode hints:

```
Map<EncodeHintType, String> hints = new HashMap<>();
hints.put(EncodeHintType.FORCE_CODE_SET, "B");
BitMatrix matrix = writer.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, width, height, hints);
```

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds. Have an upvote.

Comment: Can you provide a code example on how to use FORCE_CODE_SET

Comment: @malz done, just showing the basic idea, may not compile

Comment: It works perfectly fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

While I haven't reverse-engineered the exact data in your barcodes, I do note that the Wikipedia article on Code 128 mentions that it supports [three different encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128#Subtypes) of data, including the ability to swap between different encodings multiple times within the same barcode.

Presumably, different implementations use different strategies for encoding characters into the barcodes, with ZXing finding a more compact way to encode your digits than Labelary does.

If this hunch is true, the two barcodes express the same data in two different, but equivalent, ways.